# How to use current_user with before_save in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Using rails_admin I want to check if the current_user is the same user who originally created the object before he can update a specific field (a different user has to check a 'approved' field). If the users are the same the save should be aborted.

I can get the original user using something like object.versions.first.whodunnit but I'm struggling to get the current_user. The object in question has no association to the user_model (which is solely used for rails_admin -> there are no 'regular' users).

In the model I can't access current_user and I don't know how to access the controller used by rails_admin.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. 'PaperTrail.whodunnit' can be used in the model get the current_user. So I added a custom validation an used

```
self.versions.first.whodunnit.to_i == PaperTrail.whodunnit.id
```

to check if the original creator of the object is the same as the person who is about to approve the current version of this object.

If anybody know a better solution, please let me know.